# Получение прямой ссылки на скачивание файла из телеграмм чата, без необходимости скачивать этот файл к себе на компьютер

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

Требуется получить ссылку на прямое скачивание файла из чата телеграмм, чтобы вставить в метод апи яндекс диска upload_by_link или upload_url, так, чтобы не нужно было скачивать файл себе на компьютер.
Использую библиотеку pyrogram, но можно взять другую если это будет работать, буду рад любому решению, главное чтобы была возможность работать с большими файлами.

Заранее спасибо за любой ответ!